# double takes the value NaN after 0/0

Tags: java, double

I have this class that works on pixels of a sequence of images

```
    private int makeRSR(int x, int y)
    {   
      double bRed = 0;double bGreen = 0; double bBlue = 0;
      for(int k: sequence.keySet())
      {
        BufferedImage img = sequence.get(k);
        for(int i=0; i<iteration; i++){ 
            for(int j=0;j<spray_int; j++){ 
                int dist= ((int)(dis_int*Math.random()));
                double theta=((int)(361*Math.random())) ;
                double inc_x=dist * Math.cos((theta*(Math.PI/180)));
                double inc_y=dist * Math.sin((theta*(Math.PI/180)));
                int row=Math.abs((int)(inc_y+y));
                int column=Math.abs((int)(inc_x+x));
                if(row<1 || column<1 || row>altI-1 || column>largI-1){
                    row=Math.abs((int) ((altI-1)*Math.random()));
                    column=Math.abs((int) ((largI-1)*Math.random()));
                }
                Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(column,row));
                red.add(c.getRed());
                green.add(c.getGreen());
                blue.add(c.getBlue());
            }
            Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(x,y));
            red.add(c.getRed());
            green.add(c.getGreen());
            blue.add(c.getBlue());

            double maxR=max(red);
            double maxG=max(green);
            double maxB=max(blue);

            bRed += ((((double)c.getRed()) / (maxR))*255.00);
            bGreen += ((((double)c.getGreen()) / (maxG))*255.00);
            bBlue += ((((double)c.getBlue()) / (maxB))*255.00); 

            red.clear();green.clear();blue.clear();
        }
    }

    redValue=0;greenValue=0;blueValue=0;
    redValue= (int) (bRed/(iteration*(sequence.size())));
    greenValue= (int) (bGreen/(iteration*(sequence.size())));
    blueValue=(int) (bBlue/(iteration*(sequence.size())));

    bRed=0.0;bGreen=0.0;bBlue=0.0;

    return new Color(redValue,greenValue,blueValue).getRGB();
}
```

the problem is that sometimes c.getRed() and maxR are both 0 (same for the other channels) and so bRed loses its content and take value NaN, and it never change. Is there an error, something I missed, or do I have to prevent the 0/0 by adding a check?
Thanks, Bye

Comment: A simple way to avoid this it to decide what you want to happen and produce an equation which avoids this. e.g. `bRed += 255.0 * c.getRed() / (maxR + 1e-3);`

Comment: @PeterLawrey using an `if` is, however, much cleaner and IMHO even simpler.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse `if` or `maxR == 0 ? 0.0 : ... ` could be much clearer, esp if the behaviour you want doesn't fit into an equation easily.

Answer (score 3):

Since `0/0` is an undefined number you need to decide how do you want do treat it.

1. Find out why you get both 0 in current and max red values and prevent it.
2. Set result of division to 0 (or any number you decide to get the expected result) if both `c.getRed()` and `maxR` are 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because dividing by zero is an error, it results in `NaN`, which stands for Not a Number. Subsequent operations involving `NaN` will also result in `NaN`, that's why it's value never changes afterwards.

You should explicitly check for zero divident before division to prevent division by zero.